# How can I find issue by user Springboot Jira API?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jira, jira-rest-api

I am working on a project in which I have to get existing Jira issues for a specific user. I have implemented the Jira REST API exactly how they show it on [Baeldung.com](https://www.baeldung.com/jira-rest-api) but I have not found any api to get all issues for a user without having to use an ID.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The client library you mentioned from the article doesn't provide any method for retrieval of all the issues. You need to call search REST api directly which uses jql.

https://developer.atlassian.com/server/jira/platform/jira-rest-api-examples/#searching-for-issues-examples

There is parameter jql where you can query for a user

```
jpql=assignee%20%3D%20557058%3Ac64112ec-589f-4b56-8bb6-9eea49e26364
```

The string after jpql= must be url encoded

Answer (score 1):

Integrating a Spring Boot API with a Jira Board
This guide explains how to integrate a Spring Boot API with a Jira board using Jira's REST APIs.

Prerequisites
A Jira Cloud account with administrative privileges.
Basic knowledge of Spring Boot.
An API token generated from your Jira account (https://id.atlassian.com/manage-profile/security/api-tokens).
Step 1: Set Up Spring Boot Project
First, create a new Spring Boot project. You can use Spring Initializr (https://start.spring.io/) to help you with this. Add the following dependencies to your pom.xml file:

Spring Web
Spring Boot Starter Data JPA (optional, if you need database interaction)
OkHttp (For making HTTP requests)
Step 2: Generate Jira API Token
Next, generate an API token from your Jira Cloud account. This token will be used for authenticating your requests to Jira's API.

Log in to https://id.atlassian.com/manage-profile/security/api-tokens.
Click 'Create API token'.
Name your token and then click 'Create'.
Click 'Copy to clipboard'. Store the token securely.
Step 3: Create a Jira Service in Spring Boot
Create a JiraService class in your Spring Boot application. This service will handle making HTTP requests to Jira's REST APIs. Here's a sample method for getting an issue:

Replace "your-jira-url" with your Jira Cloud URL and "your-api-token" with the API token you generated.

Step 4: Create a Spring Boot Controller
Next, create a controller that calls methods from JiraService. This controller will expose endpoints that your users or other services can call:

In this code, getIssue corresponds to the GET HTTP method for the path /api/jira/issue/{issueKey}. This method will return the response from Jira's API as the body of the HTTP response.

Step 5: Test Your Integration
After completing the steps above, you can start your Spring Boot application and make a GET request to `http://localhost:8080/api/jira/issue/{

Answer (score 0):

```java
@Service
public class JiraService {

    private static final String JIRA_URL = "https://your-jira-url/rest/api/2/";
    private static final String JIRA_USERNAME = "your-username";
    private static final String JIRA_PASSWORD = "your-password";

    private OkHttpClient client;

    public JiraService() {
        this.client = new OkHttpClient();
    }

    public String getIssue(String issueKey) throws IOException {
        Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url(JIRA_URL + "issue/" + issueKey)
                .header("Authorization", Credentials.basic(JIRA_USERNAME, JIRA_PASSWORD))
                .build();

        try (Response response = client.newCall(request).execute()) {
            return response.body().string();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```
@RestController
```

@RequestMapping("/api/jira")
public class JiraController {

```
private final JiraService jiraService;

@Autowired
public JiraController(JiraService jiraService) {
    this.jiraService = jiraService;
}

@GetMapping("/issue/{issueKey}")
public ResponseEntity<String> getIssue(@PathVariable String issueKey) {
    try {
        String issue = jiraService.getIssue(issueKey);
        return ResponseEntity.ok(issue);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).body("Error occurred while getting the issue");
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).